# Symfony2: several bundles to access name values stored in a database

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony2 and I am porting an old Symfony1 app to v2.

In my old app, I defined all of my models in one great big YML file. So the various 'components' were able to reference the same name value pairs (stored in the YML file).

I am now factoring out the functionality into bundles, and I want to completely decouple the bundles. I still need to access the name value pairs, but I want to store it centrally - in a database this time.

I want to keep my code DRY and so want to write the code for accessing the name value pairs only ONCE and some how use that in the separate bundles.

I also, want to provide centralised CRUD facilities for maintaining the name value pairs.

To summarise, my 2 questions are as follows:

1. How can I provide functionality (implemented once) to access name value pairs stored in a database, and make this functionality available to bundles that require it?
2. What is the best way to provide CRUD functionality for maintainance of the name value pairs? (is it by creating yet another bundle?)
   I am not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You can create a Doctrine entity and request the keys you need. In order to code DRY, use a base entity and extend it to each pair type:

   **`Pair` entity:**

   ```
   namespace MyBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @MappedSuperclass
    */
   class Pair
   {
       /**
        * @Column(type="string", unique=true)
        * @var string
        */
       protected $name;

       /**
        * @Column(type="string")
        * @var string
        */
       protected $value;

       // Getters & setters
       // ...
   }
   ```

   **`SportPair` entity:**

   ```
   namespace MyBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

   /**
    * @Entity(repositoryClass="MyBundle\Entity\PairRepository")
    * @Table(name="sport_pairs")
    */
   class SportPair extends Pair
   {
       /**
        * @Id
        * @GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
        * @Column(name="id", type="integer")
        * @var int
        */
       protected $id;
   }
   ```

   **`Pair` repository:**

   ```
   namespace MyBundle\Entity;

   use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

   class PairRepository extends EntityRepository
   {
       private $cache = array();

       public function getValue($key)
       {
           if (!isset($this->cache[$key])) {
               $pair = $this->findOneBy(array('name' => $key));
               if (null !== $pair) {
                   $this->cache[$key] = $pair->getValue();
               }
           }

           return $this->cache[$key];
       }
   }
   ```
2. Use `SensioGenerationBundle` to generate CRUD to manager `Pair` entities.

---

That's how you should proceed:

1. Create your application bundle (`MyAppBundle`).
2. ***(optional)*** Create a shared bundle (`MySharedBundle`)
3. Reference the bundles into the application kernel.
4. Create `Pair` and `PairRepository` into `MyAppBundle`.
5. ***(optional)*** Move those classes to `MySharedBundle`
6. Create derived pair classes into `MyAppBundle`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I want to make sure that I understand your proposed solution correctly. In the example above, the namespace used seems to suggest that the Pair (and PairRepository) entity code is written for **each** bundle?. Is my understanding correct? (i.e. each bundle will have its Pair and PairRepository classes copied into its folder)?. I was trying to avoid such an approach because it is **NOT DRY**. Please clarify.

Comment: You can share code between bundles. You write it once, then reuse the bundle. That's how  Symfony's `FrameworkBundle` works.

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do (i.e. write it once, then reuse the bundle). However I don't see how your answer addressed this - unless `MyBundle` (from your snippet) is a new bundle that is used **purely** to fetch/list a particular pair. In which case, it is still not clear to me. For example if I have the following name pair lists: ReadingCategory, SportsCategory, FoodCategory, **1.** Do I need to create 3 separate bundles, (one bundle dedicated to each name pair list)?. **2.** How do I (for example) refer to `BundleA` from `BundleB` in code?

Comment: **1.** I've edited my answer to handle multiple pair types. Just create as many entity classes as you need. **2.** Reference each bundle into your `AppKernel` and then use classes with the correct namespace.

Comment: thanks for your help. Let me just make sure that I understand you correctly. This is how I should proceed:. **1.** Create a NamePairBundle. **2.** Create all the required pairs (as doctrine entries) in the bundle. I assume that each different entity (e.g. SportPair etc), will need their own EntityRepository derived class? [I previously used Propel, so I am new to Doctrine] **3.** Reference each bundle into my `AppKernel` and then use classes with the correct namespace.  Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Thanks. I will try and implement this to prove I understand it correctly, then I will accept your answer.